# color detection system with python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, colors, detection

im trying to make a color detection system with python opencv this is what i have done so far. im still new to python so please help me thank you

basically what should happen is that when the user opens this application the camera open and when he clicks anywhere on the window it will tell the name of the color

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import cv2
import numpy as np
import webcolors

def click_event(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        blue = cap[y, x, 0]
        green = cap[y, x, 1]
        red = cap[y, x, 2]
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

        #colourcode = str(blue) + ", " + str(green) + ", " + str(red)
        colourcode2 = (red, green, blue)

        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

        def closest_colour(requested_colour):
            min_colours = {}
            for key, name in webcolors.css3_hex_to_names.items():
                r_c, g_c, b_c = webcolors.hex_to_rgb(key)
                rd = (r_c - requested_colour[0]) ** 2
                gd = (g_c - requested_colour[1]) ** 2
                bd = (b_c - requested_colour[2]) ** 2
                min_colours[(rd + gd + bd)] = name
            return min_colours[min(min_colours.keys())]

        def get_colour_name(requested_colour):
            try:
                closest_name = actual_name = webcolors.rgb_to_name(requested_colour)
            except ValueError:
                closest_name = closest_colour(requested_colour)
                actual_name = None
            return actual_name, closest_name


        #print(colourcode2)
        requested_colour = colourcode2
        actual_name, closest_name = get_colour_name(requested_colour)

        #print("colour name:", closest_name)
        cv2.putText(img, closest_name, (0, 50), font, 1, 255, 2)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0);
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(40) == 27:
        break



cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: what is the problem ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is your problem but using your code I create version which works for me

I use `cv2.setMouseCallback` to assign your function to mouse click. It gets pixel from `frame`, not `cap`. Pixel is a list/tuple of (B,G,R) so I revere it `list[::-1]`. After I get name of color I assign it to external/global variable, not put on frame. In main loop I use this name to put on frame before it will display it.

I also use `EVENT_LBUTTONUP` to remove text when I release mouse button.

```
 elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
      closest_name = ''
```

If you remove above lines then it will keep text when you release mouse button.

```
import cv2
import webcolors

# --- functions ---

def closest_colour(requested_colour):
    min_colours = {}
    for key, name in webcolors.css3_hex_to_names.items():
        r_c, g_c, b_c = webcolors.hex_to_rgb(key)
        rd = (r_c - requested_colour[0]) ** 2
        gd = (g_c - requested_colour[1]) ** 2
        bd = (b_c - requested_colour[2]) ** 2
        min_colours[(rd + gd + bd)] = name
    return min_colours[min(min_colours.keys())]

def get_colour_name(requested_colour):
    try:
        closest_name = actual_name = webcolors.rgb_to_name(requested_colour)
    except ValueError:
        closest_name = closest_colour(requested_colour)
        actual_name = None
    return actual_name, closest_name

def click_event(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global closest_name # inform function to assign to global/external variable instead of creating local one

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        #B, G, R = frame[x, y]
        #colour = (R, G, B)  # reverse values
        colour = frame[y,x][::-1] # reverse values
        actual_name, closest_name = get_colour_name(colour)
        print(actual_name, closest_name)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        closest_name = ''

# --- main ---

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

closest_name = '' # create global variable at start

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0);

cv2.namedWindow('frame')
cv2.setMouseCallback('frame', click_event)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if closest_name:
        #print(closest_name)
        cv2.putText(frame, closest_name, (10, 30), font, 1, (255,255,255), 2)

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(40) == 27:
        break

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

cap.release()
```

---

In all GUIs when you press button then it creates single event `EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN` - it doesn't generate it again and again when you keep button pressed. So function `click_event` is executed only once and your version puts text only on one frame but few miliseconds later main loop gets new frame and displays it without text - so finally you don't see text on frame.